# Not returns dates well into Java App Engine

Tags: java, date, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I hope you can help me with this case

this is my query:

```java
List operationList = 
ofy().load().type(Operation.class).filter(compositeFilter).order("-date").order("-codeOperation").list();
```

When I try to order a query in app engine java, by date, I find that it does not order the query correctly.

This is the case I have:

three records:

- the first one has the date like this 10/09/2019 (09:21:00)
- the second like this 10/09/2019 (12:20:12)
- and the third one is like this 10/09/2019 (13:28:00)

but the order given by app engine is the opposite

**first 10/09/2019 (12:20:12) second 10/09/2019 (09:21:00) third 10/09/2019 (13:28:00)**

When the correct way to do the query is:

**First 10/09/2019 (09:21:00) second 10/09/2019 (12:20:12) third 10/09/2019 (13:28:00)**

I have tried in several ways but I can't find a solution, I appreciate your help to improve this process.

Comment: Could you please tell me what data type is the "date" property? Could you, also tell me what kind of comparison operator do your compositeFilter specifies?

Answer (score 1):

The order

> first 10/09/2019 (12:20:12) second 10/09/2019 (09:21:00) third 10/09/2019 (13:28:00)

is not sorted at all. Since you are using "-date" implying sort descending, the order you should be getting is

```
10/09/2019 (13:28:00)
10/09/2019 (12:20:12) 
10/09/2019 (09:21:00)
```

Comment: That's what I want to return, but app engine does not do it that way, the dates that range between 12, all are at the beginning as if you were the first records of the day